# how to obtain p.m.f from p.g.f

Tags: probability

Hoping someone can shine some light. I'm new to this and especially to this particular formula. The way I've had it explained is hard to understand for me.

**Question:**$$\prod(s) = \frac19(2 + s^2)^2$$

**Answer:**

The p.g.f. can be rewritten as $\prod(s) = \frac19(4 + 4s^2 + s^4) =\frac49 + \frac49s^2 + \frac19s^4$.

The probabilities $p(x) = P(X = x)$ can be picked out: $p(0) = 4/9 , p(2) = 4/9 , p(4) = 1/9$.

Can someone walk me through how you get that answer?

Comment: Welcome to the website. Use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your math equations in future (I have done it for you this time).

Comment: What you've written does not appear to be a question. Might it be that some words appeared that said "If the following is a probability generating function, find the probabbility mass function?" or something to that effect? You've omitted that here.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability generating function of a discrete random variable $X$ is given by$$G_X(s)=E[s^X]=\sum_{x=0}^\infty s^xp(X=x)$$Note that the coefficient of $s^t$ is the probability that $X=t$. You are given $G_X(s)=\frac49s^0 + \frac49s^2 + \frac19s^4$, thus$$P(X=0)=\text{co-efficient of }s^0=4/9\\P(X=2)=\text{co-efficient of }s^2=4/9\\P(X=4)=\text{co-efficient of }s^4=1/9$$Note that $X$ doesn't take any other value because $(1)$ the sum of probabilities is $1$, and $(2)$ there is no other power of $s$ in $G_X(s)$ i.e. there co-efficients are $0$.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain to me how you get the coefficients? And why do we skip 1 and 3 etc?

Comment: When $G_X(s)$ is expressed in the form $p_0s^0+p_1s^1+p_2s^2+...$, the coefficient of $s^k$ is $p_k$. Note that in our case, only $s^0,s^2,s^4$ appear with non-zero coefficients in $\frac49s^0 + \frac49s^2 + \frac19s^4$. The remaining powers of $s$ don't appear in $G_X(s)$ i.e. their coefficients are $0$.

Comment: ahh right, thank you so much!